# PHP ftp_put replacing a file from a dev site to a live site

Tags: php, file, ftp, directory

I'm simply trying to replace a file using ftp, both destinations are on the same server

New File: `/home/srv/dev_html/test.php`
Old File:    `/home/srv/public_html/test.php`

```
$new = "/home/srv/dev_html/test.php";
$old = "/home/srv/public_html/test.php";

$tmp = explode("/",$new);
$newfile = end($tmp);
$newdir = str_replace($newfile,"",$new);

ftp_chdir($conn_id,$newdir); //try changing directory

ftp_put($conn_id, $old, $newfile, FTP_ASCII);
```

Error occurs on ftp_chdir, saying 
`ftp_chdir(): Can't change directory to /home/srv/dev_html/: No such file or directory`
I've confirmed it exists using `file_exists()`.
Does that mean you can't use absolute paths?
 If not what is a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use ftp_rename function instead

```
ftp_rename($conn_id, $old, $newfile);
```

See details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rename.php

Comment: `ftp_rename(): Sorry, but that file doesn't exist` however `echo file_exists($old);` returns 1

Comment: `file_exists` will check in your server. while `ftp_rename` will check in the ftp connected server.